# Weird behaviour in Barcode Scanner (Android)

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am developing an Android application and I am currently having some troubles running Barcode Scanner (Zxing). I'm using Zxing as a "library project" in Eclipse.

I built Zxing core project with Ant, created my Zxing android project by importing sources in Eclipse and ticking the "Is Library" box. (That project uses the "core.jar" in its dependencies.)

Then I have my main project, which uses the Zxing library project, that project, uses the "core.jar" too.

So, here is the problem, when I run my application and start my Barcode Scanner Intent,
here is what I see on the screen :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/screenbarcodescanner.png/
(I am sorry but I don't have enough reputation to post my screen here)

The strange thing is that it seems to recognize some things when I put my hand in front of the camera or some barcode, QR Code (it doesn't scan, but there are some green dots appearing on the red line, you know, it is a bit hard to aim the code without seeing anything on the screen ;) )

Finally, here is the way I am calling the Intent and managing the result, the basic way, as it is written on the Zxing Google code page :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View sender)
{
    if(sender.equals(_scan_button))
    {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"), 0);
    }
    // ...
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            //String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // ...handle the result
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

I don't actually provide the code format to the Intent because I want it to scan any code format.

Last thing I can say, is that, before doing this with Zxing as a library project, I was using just as a "project dependency", that way, Zxing apk was installed on my phone if not installed, before running the main project. All was working very well, now it is embedded,...I'm stuck and I don't really why or what I am missing.

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You're mixed up here. If you integrate by Intent, you do not need any code from Barcode Scanner. In the project, all you may need is the small bit of integration code you find in `android-integration`. This ought to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't really integrate by Intent, I saw this section in Zxing documentation, about `android-integration`, but...I think I'm lost.

Actually I just want to be able to launch the scanner, without having Barcode Scanner app installed already.

For now, I configured my project to be "project-dependent" of the Zxing Eclipse project. That way, when I install my apk on the phone, Eclipse (or adb) recognize the dependency, and install Zxing just before install my app.
The "problem" is that the user will see after that, that Barcode Scanner has been installed on his phone (even if he didn't want to)!

Comment: For this, you would need to have an understanding of Eclipse, Android projects, and the Barcode Scanner source. If it's presenting problems, I think your only choice is Intent.